# Flume channel Capacity is full giving exception

Tags: hadoop-streaming, flume-twitter

I have started flume Twitteragent to fetch the twitter data into the hdfs after few mins the data was not able to write to the hdfs it was poping a message in the terminal as mentioned below.

***Error***

org.apache.flume.ChannelException: Take list for MemoryTransaction, capacity 100 full, consider committing more frequently, increasing capacity, or increasing thread count at org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel$MemoryTransaction.doTake(MemoryChannel.java:101)at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.take(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:113)at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.take(BasicChannelSemantics.java:95)at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:391)at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:853)2015-10-16 15:14:18,126 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERRORorg.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)] Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: org.apache.flume.ChannelException: Take list for MemoryTransaction, capacity 100 full, consider committing more frequently, increasing capacity, or increasing thread count

I guess we need to increase the channel capacity but not sure needed a help.

Comment: Is the problem related to a higher "producing" rate (at the sources) than "consuming" rate (at the sinks)? Or is it because any event is being stored in HDFS? If it is the second, you may have a chance to fix it. If it is the first, even configuring the greatest channel, the problem will arise the sooner or later.